# How to make new model attributes show in active admin dashboard?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I'm working on a sign-up app in Rails, and I'm using active admin to manage it. New attributes added to the model aren't showing in active admin.

I've decided to add an attribute to one of the models and I've added it in the db folder. I've then run db:migrate.

However, the new attribute is not appearing in admin view.

Here is my code from the create file:

```
    class CreateRegistrations < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
       def change
    create_table :registrations do |t|
       t.string :first_name
       t.string :last_name
       t.string :gender
       t.string :email
       t.string :nationality
       t.string :religion
       t.date :birthdate
       t.string :phone
       t.string :streetname
       t.string :city
       t.string :state
       t.string :zip
       t.boolean :need_ride
       t.string :has_spouse
       t.string :spouse_name
       t.string :english_level
       t.text :expectations
       t.string :length_of_stay
       t.text :exact_length
       t.integer :volunteer_partner
       t.boolean :matched

  t.timestamps
       end
    end
end
```

I've added the last attribute- :matched, to params and to permitted params in both the controller and in the admin model.

It still is not showing up.

Any thoughts, suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please check in the database that the attribute `matched` actually added. I am assuming you didn't added the attribute when you create `registration` table, did you?

Comment: No it was added after the creation of the model. I will double check to make sure it was added

Comment: You're right! Just checked and for some reason it hasn't been added to the database. I'm not sure why it wouldn't migrate.

Comment: You said 'I've added it in the db folder' - did you run `rails generate migration AddMatchedToYourModel matched:boolean`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the migration `CreateRegistrations` already ran, when you first create the `registration` table. After running a migration if you change that migration file and run `db:migrate` again it won't see the update you did to that migration file.

To add the new attribute you should create a new migration file by running the following command:

```
rails generate migration AddMatchedToYourModel matched:boolean
```

It should create a new migration file. And then run `rails db:migrate` again.

Comment: Thanks, I completely forgot about generating a migration!